# Conditional regex string substitution in Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string that can either be something like

```
create
```

or

```
create by
```

depending on the verb, etc. In Ruby (on Rails) to get the past tense

```
string.sub(/e?$/, "ed")
```

or

```
string.sub(/ by?$/, "ed by")
```

works, but is there any way to combine the two? With some type of conditional statement or similar.

Comment: check this out - https://github.com/rossmeissl/verbs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using word boundary (`\b`):

```
'create by'.sub(/e\b/, 'ed')
# => "created by"
'create'.sub(/e\b/, 'ed')
# => "created"
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add that the verb can end with anything. I have hacked it to work with sub(/(e?$| )\b/, "ed "). I just don't like the space at the end of the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Why not?

```
2.1.0-preview2 :046 > 'create'.sub('create', 'created')
 => "created"
2.1.0-preview2 :047 > 'create by'.sub('create', 'created')
 => "created by"
```

And no regexps... )